# Dual booting unix from /dev/sdb

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, grub2

I know there are many dual-boot posts already, but I have tried most of the solutions without success. My situation differs slightly.

I have 2 hard disks. I am running Windows 7 and Ubuntu on sda1 (both are working well) and trying to install back-track to sdb (it is an SSD).

However, when I select backtrack from the GRUB menu, i get the error message:
no such device: 3c19f052-1344-4e54-878a-4f7849e7882c
hd1 cannot get C/H/S values
you need to load the kernel first

I have re-installed several times, and during install, I always choose to install GRUB to /dev/sdb. (Chose sda once and it could not boot any of the other 2x OS as well)

Info from boot-repair is posted at http://paste.ubuntu.com/6414903/ --> everything seems in order. Does any1 have any hints?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a BIOS problem. [This article](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2064395.html) mentions similar problems using a SSD as a second bootable-disk.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you stumbled on the same problem I set up a feature request on grub2 for: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?41005 .

The problem is that your BIOS does not expect a second HDD - but a ODD (optical disk drive) on the connect port. Normally the problem results from modifying the hdd/odd configuration of a laptop.